# Can't resize box in canvas using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

So my problem should be simple - I can't resize the box size in canvas using tkinter. I created a blank canvas and want to display information using a box (called profiling_box) within the canvas. But the box is too small and won't change size. I'm not sure why this is happening when I can change the placement of the box and the size of the canvas. I am using jupyterlab from anaconda btw. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from IPython.display import display

def show_profile(event):
    selected_index = profiles_listbox.curselection()[0]
    selected_profile = profiles[selected_index]
    
    profile_text.delete("1.0", tk.END)
    profile_text.insert(tk.END, f"First Name: {selected_profile['first_name']}\n")
    profile_text.insert(tk.END, f"Last Name: {selected_profile['last_name']}\n")
    profile_text.insert(tk.END, f"Address: {selected_profile['address']}\n")
    profile_text.insert(tk.END, f"Phone: {selected_profile['phone']}\n")
    profile_text.insert(tk.END, f"Email: {selected_profile['email']}\n")
    profile_text.insert(tk.END, f"Email Score: {selected_profile['email_score']}\n")
    profile_text.insert(tk.END, f"Contact Preference: {selected_profile['contact_preference']}\n")
    profile_text.insert(tk.END, f"Age: {selected_profile['age']}\n")
    profile_text.insert(tk.END, f"Ethnicity: {selected_profile['ethnicity']}\n")
    profile_text.insert(tk.END, f"Gender: {selected_profile['gender']}\n")
    profile_text.insert(tk.END, f"Marital Status: {selected_profile['marital_status']}\n")
    profile_text.insert(tk.END, f"Education: {selected_profile['education']}\n")
    profile_text.insert(tk.END, f"Employment: {selected_profile['employment']}\n")
    profile_text.insert(tk.END, f"Income: {selected_profile['income']}\n")
    profile_text.insert(tk.END, f"Vehicles Owned: {', '.join(selected_profile['vehicles_owned'])}\n")
    profile_text.insert(tk.END, f"Customer Status: {selected_profile['customer_status']}\n")
    profile_text.insert(tk.END, f"Calls to Customer Support: {selected_profile['calls_to_customer_support']}\n")

profiles = [
    {
        "first_name": "Brimstone",
        "last_name": "Bloodhound",
        "address": "9 Clinton Street, Steamwood, IL 60107",
        "phone": "123-666-4567",
        "email": "1@email.com",
        "email_score": 10,
        "contact_preference": ";)",
        "age": 29,
        "ethnicity": "Traffic Cone",
        "gender": "Water",
        "marital_status": "Got evicted frfr",
        "education": "BS",
        "employment": "Unemployed",
        "income": 100000000,
        "vehicles_owned": ["Gundam", "Eva"],
        "customer_status": "Prospect",
        "calls_to_customer_support": 'are you sure about that'
    }
]

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Profile Viewer")

#Canvas
#I can change canvas size no problem
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=1200, height=300, bg="white")
canvas.pack()





# Create profiling box
#can't resize -- width started at 150, but I kept on going up till it reached 11150. the size still didn't change -- same thing with height
profiling_box = tk.Frame(canvas, width=11150, height=11250, bg="lightgray")
#but I can change the position no problem
profiling_box.place(x=550, y=10)

# Create profile text box inside profiling box
profile_text = tk.Text(profiling_box, width=30, height=15)
profile_text.pack(padx=10, pady=10)





# Create profile listbox on the right
profiles_listbox = tk.Listbox(root, width=30)
for profile in profiles:
    profiles_listbox.insert(tk.END, f"{profile['first_name']} {profile['last_name']}")
profiles_listbox.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=20, pady=20)

# Bind the selection event
profiles_listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", show_profile)

# Display the Tkinter window using IPython's display function
display(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

A canvas is a special beast that works very differently from frames.  In order to place a Frame window on a canvas, you have to use `create_window`:

```
profiling_box = tk.Frame(root, width=75, height=50, bg="red")
canvas.create_window( 230, 230, width=100, height=50,window=profiling_box)
```